# php database insert function

Tags: php, sql

I am going through an article in nettuts.com and it is about building a twitter clone and there is a function in the code that does standard inserts into the database.Here is the code

```
    private function insert($table, $arr){

        $query = "INSERT INTO" . $table . " (";
        $pref = "";

        foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
                $query .= $pref . $key;
                $pref = ", ";
            }
            $query .= ") VALUES (";
            $pref = "";
            foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
                $query .= $pref. "'" . $value . "'";
                $pref = ", ";
            }
            $query = .= ");";
            return $this->db->query($query);
    }
```

what I am having trouble understanding is the $pref variable.Can someone explain its purpose to me?

Comment: It's a quite unusual, but perfectly servicable, way to put comma's between arguments in a list without having it begin or end with a comma.

Comment: It adds the comma in front of every element except the first: `1,2,3,4,5`

Comment: Must be a really old tutorial because it has SQL Injection written all over it. Take a look at PDO and try to use that for the twitter clone. Don't learn bad practices. They are hard to unlearn when you progress.

Comment: aaah! ok now i saw what it does the $pref="" is there so there is no comma on the first element.Thank you!

Comment: i have tested your code $table='users';
 $arr=array('id'=>7,'name'=>'nanhe','email'=>'nanhe26');
 echo insert($table, $arr); INSERT INTO users (id, name, email) VALUES ('7', 'nanhe', 'nanhe26'); its perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a way of having commas only in between the values in `VALUES('like','this','and','this')`
because `$pref` is still set to "" the first time it's value and the key is appended to `$query` they will always have a comma before the value except the first one:

```
    $query .= $pref . $key;
    $pref = ", ";
```

Answer (score 0):

Silly mistake in your code

```
$query = "INSERT INTO" . $table . " (";
```

Need to space after INTO

```
$query = "INSERT INTO " . $table . " (";
$query .= ") VALUES (";
$query  .= ");";
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also use the implode() function http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php to create a string from the $arr array!

```
  implode(", ", array_keys($arr));
```